# Django Cycle Includes Template Tags

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to cycle the include tags in a django template, but I am unable to nest cycle inside of includes.  The cycle should be like

```
include cycle left_align.html right_align.html
```

I am trying to avoid creating a custom template just to keep it simple.  I wanted to see if anyone had any suggestions of how to do this:

```
{% for s in sections %}

<section class="{% cycle 'lighter-section' 'cover cover-bg-section' %}">
    {% if s.media.values %}

    {% include 'web_builder/apple-pie/sections/left_align.html' %}

    {% else %}

    {% include 'web_builder/apple-pie/sections/center_align.html' %}

    {% endif %}
</section>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to assign result of `cycle` templatetag to a variable with `with` block but you can use `as` keyword to dump its result to the variable and use it wherever you wish e.g. `{% cycle 'left_align.html' 'right_align.html' as include_file %}`. However this has a side effect.

This instruction itself produces cycle result although it is also registered in the variable. As a work-around you can place it for instance in a `data-` attr of some HTML element so that it isn't displayed and use the variable later in full template path concatenation inside `include` tag.

Full example:

```
  {% for i in "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" %}
    <section data-include-file="{% cycle 'left_align.html' 'right_align.html' as include_file %}">
    {% include 'web_builder/apple-pie/sections/'|add:include_file %}
    </section>
  {% endfor %}
```

However since it looks ugly and complicated I would also consider writing custom inclusion tag for that.